# How to automatically click a href link when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, blogger, blogspot

I'm trying to automatically click a `href` link when the page loads.

```
<div class="loadmore" kind="rb">
  <a href="javascript:;" target="_self">تحميل المزيد...</a>
</div>
```

The link is supposed to load more comments when you click it.

I tried this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    autoloadmore()
};

function autoloadmore() {
    var loadmoreClass = document.getElementsByClassName("loadmore")[0];
    var loadmoreChild = loadmoreClass.getElementsByTagName("a");

    if(loadmoreClass){
          loadmoreChild[0].click();
    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work. The problem seems to be with `click()`, because when I use other codes such as `.style.color`, they work.

I'm using Blogger by the way.

This's a sample blog:

http://blog-sample-001.blogspot.com/2018/09/title.html

(go to تحميل المزيد...)

ps: I can't change the div.

Comment: `window.onload = function() { document.querySelector('a').click() };` this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

Assign some `ID` to `<a href="javascript:;" target="_self">تحميل المزيد...</a>` . For example, `clickAfterPageLoad` or whatever you want, and then try this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#clickAfterPageLoad").trigger('click');
});
```

or if you cant't change `div`, you can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".loadmore a").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: As I said, I cant't change div, or what's inside.